# Inheritance of independence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I want to show the following statement: let $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ be sequences of random variables and $X_n\perp Y_n$ for each $n$. If $X_n\to X$ and $Y_n\to Y$ in probability respectively, then $X\perp Y$. How can I prove this without using characteristic function?

Comment: How would you prove this with characteristic functions? I don't think characteristic functions see anything about independence, they only see the distribution... right? Or does $\phi_{X + Y} = \phi_X \phi_Y$ imply independence?

Answer (score 2):

Passing to subsequences, we can assume that the convergence is almost sure. 
Using the dominated convergence theorem, we obtain for each continuous and bounded functions $f$ and $g$ that 
$$\mathbb E\left[f(X)g(Y) \right]=\mathbb E[f(X)]\mathbb E[g(Y)].$$
Now pick $x,y\in\mathbf R$ and approximate pointwise the indicator function of the intervals $(-\infty,x)$ and $(-\infty,y)$ by sequences of continuous and bounded functions (for simplicity, piecewise linear).